# Create a logic captcha from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I haven't touched a scrap of code yet, but here's my thoughts on how to do this:

Create a `:interactions` entry in my `session` hash. This will contain an array of time stamps. Every time a user goes through any action, the time they did this will be appended to the `:interactions` entry. The array will be initialized in my sessions controller, and timestamps appended to it via a filter in my application controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        create_session
        session[:interactions] = []
    end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    after_action :log_time

    private

    def log_time
        session[:interactions] << Time.now.to_i
    end
end
```

Then, create another action in my application controller, the one tasked with launching the recaptcha if the user's behaviour is suspicious. All it does is see when we have 20 entries in our `session[:interactions]` array, find out the time elapsed between each pair of consecutive entries, and then find the average time elapsed between these interactions. If the average time is under two minutes, the recaptcha is launched. The `session[interactions]` array is then reset.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    after_action :log_time
    before_action :launch_captcha

    private

    def launch_captcha
        if session[:interactions].length == 20


            elapsed = []

            session[:interactions].each_slice(2) do |a, b|
                elapsed << b - a
            end

            total = elapsed.inject(:+) 
            average = total / 20

            if total < 120
               # this a part I'm really not sure how to do:
               # various instance variables should be populated here
               redirect_to 'application/launch_captcha.html.erb'
            end

            session[:interactions] = []
        end
    end

    def log_time
        session[:interactions] << Time.now
    end
end
```

Now, the fact the `session[:interactions]` is reset may be a bit of a weakness; all bets are off for those twenty interactions. But I want to build on the above logic, maybe add `session[:captchas_sent]`, to the `session` hash (or even have `captchas_sent` as a column and save it to the user's record), and if the `session[:captchas_sent]` is x amount or y amount, warnings or temporary bans could come into effect.

**What are your thoughts on the above way of monitoring user behaviour?**

Here's where my knowledge of rails is starting to break down though. Once I've redirected the user to the recaptcha page, how should I proceed? I have two tables, `questions` and `answers` with a `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship between them respectively.

So a random question will come from my `questions` table, and then I'll have a form that pertains to an answer. It will be an ajax form, and have just one field, a text field for the answer. The action the form links to, `human test`, will see if the answer given is equal to one of the question's answers. **But how should the question's id be passed into this action? It couldn't be a simple hidden field, because once the spammer knows the answer to one question, his script could always set the id to that one question. So the params hash or the sessions hash maybe? I need some advice here guys.**

I also don't really know how the `human test` method should proceed once the it finds the user's answer is equal to one of the question's answers:

Let's say the user is submitting a comment. They fill in the comment, hit the submit button, the `launch_captcha` action kicks in, and redirects them to 'application/launch_captcha.html.erb'. **What has happened to the data in the comment create form?** Once they've answered the captcha correctly, how should the `human_test` method proceed? How could it go on to submit their comment as usual? I just don't know how to do that...I need to create an action that is called before the `create` action of a form...and..argh I just don't know. Help guys!